# Check if image is at the bottom when mousewheel

Tags: c#, winforms

I am enhancing a Windows Forms application which displays TIFF images.  The application has a Picturebox on top of a Panel and displays 1 image page at a time (there are thumbnails which users can click on to view a particular image).  If there are multiple images the user wants to see the next one by using an event such as the mouse wheel.  We currently have previous and next arrow button / function but they want more)

What I believe I should do is find out if the image is at the bottom during a mouse wheel event and then select the next one.  Also, same thing the opposite way, get the previous image and scroll to the bottom if they use the mouse wheel going up.

Also, I need to note that the image may be larger than the Panel so a vertical Scroll bar appears.  So, when using the mouse wheel, need to make sure it is at the bottom.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: clarification: So only one picture is displayed at once? Why see if "the image is at the bottom during a mouse wheel event"?

Comment: Yes, only displaying 1 image at a time. I guess I do not have to see if the image is at the bottom, just need a method to identify if the user is at the bottom of the image, then if they hit a mouse wheel, or even the vertical slider, to go down it will replace the current image with the next one in line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resolution to this

1) created a new variable to store the previous Vertical Scroll Value (prevVScrollVal).
2) Create a new MouseEventHandler

```
this.imageContainer.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(this.imageContainer_MouseWheel);
```

3) in Mouse Event Handler identify if up or down by looking @ the e.delta then check if the previous scroll value is the same and switch images accordingly.

```
    private void imageContainer_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            imageContainer_MouseWheelScrollUp(sender, e);
        }
        else if (e.Delta < 0)
        {
            imageContainer_MouseWheelScrollDown(sender, e);
        }

        prevVScrollVal = imageContainer.VerticalScroll.Value;
    }

    private void imageContainer_MouseWheelScrollUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (imageContainer.VerticalScroll.Value == 0 && 
            prevVScrollVal == 0 && 
            current > 1)
        {
            setPagePrev();
        }
    }

    private void imageContainer_MouseWheelScrollDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (imageContainer.VerticalScroll.Value == prevVScrollVal && 
                current < endPage)
        {
            setPageNext();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the page to the Next
    /// </summary>
    private void setPageNext()
    {
        setPage(current + 1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the page to the Previous
    /// </summary>
    private void setPagePrev()
    {
        setPage(current - 1);
        prevVScrollVal = imageContainer.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
        imageContainer.VerticalScroll.Value = imageContainer.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
        imageContainer.PerformLayout();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the page to be viewed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="page">page to be viewed</param>
    public void setPage(int page)
    {  ....  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MouseWheelEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) add an event handler on scroll and then look at e.Delta

if e.delta is positive its was scrolled up, and if negative down then just increment or decrement your image index to be displayed.

That make sense/answer your question?

Comment: you can do the same thing for the scroll bar : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.scroll.aspx

Comment: I see where you are coming at on this.  I should have mentioned that I may have an image which will be larger than the window. Lets say the Window is 760px and the image is actually 1060px.  A vertical scroll bar will be displayed so using the mouse wheel will scroll down.  What I would like to do is identify if they are at the bottom (or top) then if scroll down (or up) it would go to the next slide (or previous).

Comment: gotcha, within the MouseEventsArgs e theres the x and y pos, so if e.getY() < 'the screen height'/2  else ...

not sure about the image, thats a good point